# Why do I keep getting an undefined method error?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to reverses a string:

```
def reverse(string)
  reversed_string = ""
  string.split("") 
  string.each do |letter, idx|
    reversed_string = string.length > 0 ? letter[idx] + reversed_string : reversed_string
  end
end

reverse("abc")
```

I keep getting an error that 'split' method does not exist as well as the 'each' method.

Comment: Why not just use `'foo'.reverse`? It's faster and shorter and simpler than `'foo'.split('').reverse.join` which is faster than what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to get where you're going:

```
def reverse(s)
  ary = s.split('') # => ["f", "o", "o"], ["b", "a", "r"]
  reversed_str = ''
  ary.size.times do
    reversed_str << ary.pop # => "o", "oo", "oof", "r", "ra", "rab"
  end
  reversed_str # => "oof", "rab"
end

reverse('foo') # => "oof"
reverse('bar') # => "rab"
```

This isn't necessarily the fastest, and, if you're trying to learn how to replace a method, like `reverse`, you should try writing several different variants, then run benchmarks so you've discovered *your* fastest way of doing it. Here's how Ruby defines [`String.reverse`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L4799).

Also note that reversing a string is not the same as reversing an array. They're similar, so that'd be a good second lesson for you.

Answer (score 0):

`split` divides a string into substrings based on the provided delimiter and returns an array of these substrings, it doesn't alter the string it was called on - so you'll want to assign that to another variable and call `each` on that or just chain the methods, e.g. `string.split("").each`

As for why split isn't working, are you sure `string` is actually a string? You can call check if it is with `is_a?`, e.g. `string.is_a? String`

Comment: As far as my ternary operator, I realized it makes no sense lol. Could you help me out with making this code reverse the string using the split and each method?

Comment: You can call `reverse` on the string to reverse it in Ruby, e.g. `string.reverse` see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-reverse (you can use `reverse!` to mutate the existing string instead of returning a new one).

Comment: I'm actually re-writing the reverse method as a practice challenge, so I can't use the method itself.

Comment: `split` doesn't return a string, it returns an array of strings. Calling `reverse('abc')` will assign `"abc"` to `string`, so it'd be a String.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan for the correction, I've edited the answer.